# How to use this in jquery while storing selection in variables?

Tags: jquery

How to use `this` when storing a selection in a variable?

HTML-

```
<li><span>one</span></li>
<li><span>two</span></li>
<li><span>three</span></li>
```

For example -

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $('span', this).css(....);
});
```

We use `this` to refer to the current `<li>` that is clicked. But if we were to store them in variables, for example -

```
var li = $('li');
var span = $('span');
li.click(function(){
  span.css(....);
});
```

How to use `this` in the this case?

Comment: `$(ul,this).css(....)`

Comment: @guradio, that doesn't work

Comment: is this ul child of the click li? better show html mark up

Comment: @guradio For simplicity I replaced the `ul` with `span`

Comment: `$(span,this).css(....)` should work

Answer (score -1):

```js
var li = $('li');
var span = 'span';//dont make a jquery object here
li.click(function() {
  $(span, this).addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><span>one</span>
</li>
<li><span>two</span>
</li>
<li><span>three</span>
</li>
```

Use `$(span,this)`

Comment: This is just a hack then, instead of storing the string in the variable, why shouldn't I directly pass the string? It will save me 1 operation too